# Why is it called micalg?

Tags: digital-signature, terminology, pkcs7

[RFC3851](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3851.txt) says:

> The multipart/signed Content type has two required parameters: the
>      protocol parameter and the micalg parameter.

and

> The micalg parameter allows for one-pass processing when the
>      signature is being verified.

I haven't found any words on why it is called *micalg*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's there in the RFC in the paragraph under your quoted parts: "Message Integrity Check algorithm"